# Deciding between linear models using ANOVA

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-regression, linear-model

I am analysing data with 4 independent variables (1 a dichotomous category variable and 3 continuous variables) and have permuted these to have 15 linear models (M15 is the full model including all 4, M11-14 include 3 in each, M5-10 include 2 in each and M1-4 just one variable). I am using a 0.1 significance level and F-tests, using anova(lm15,lm14) for example. When comparing all of M11-14 to M15, the p-value is greater than 0.1, does this mean we decide there is insufficient evidence to reject those models and they are better than M15? Furthermore, when comparing all of M5-10 against the correct fuller models, the p-values are all greater than 0.1. The only test that produces less than 0.1 is between M10 and M3, so does this mean that the independent variable 3 is the only statistically significant one?

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient way to do model selection. You should try an analysis incorporating regularization, such as lasso regression. The inferences you will draw from your method are essentially meaningless.

Comment: Also, in a likelihood ratio test (which is what `anova()` does), a small p-value means the observed difference in likelihoods would be unusual if the model with fewer parameters (i.e., more restrictions) were correct.

Comment: @Noah This is the method we have been told to use. So if i do it this way, which model do you mean is the best if the p-value is low?

Comment: Low p-value means the model with more parameters is better. Also, note this technique only works if all the parameters in the smaller model are also present in the larger model.